# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'crossOrigin' in value "${crossOrigin}"

Tags: spring-data-jpa, global-variables, junit4

I am writing test case for controller class. When I am adding cross origin on top of every methods like this `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`
at that time Test cases running properly without error.

But I don't want to hard code that cross origin on top of every methods. For that I added one variable in `application.property` file and accessing that variable in controller on top of class.When I added cross origin like this I am able to access my services from other machine. But my test cases getting failed.

when I am comment this `@CrossOrigin(origins = "${crossOrigin}")` from  controller class test cases are running properly.

Can any one tell me why it's happening?

**AccountController.java**

```
    package com.spacestudy.controller;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.querydsl.core.Tuple;
    import com.spacestudy.model.Account;
    import com.spacestudy.model.*;
    import com.spacestudy.services.*;

    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "${crossOrigin}")
    @RequestMapping("/api.spacestudy.com/spacestudy/rockefeller/admin/account")
    public class AccountController {

        @Autowired
        AccountService accService;  


    @GetMapping("/loadAcctLocationList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Account>> findLocation() {
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.findLocation());
    }
```

**Application.property**

```
    crossOrigin=http://localhost:4200
    server.port=8088
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/TestDB_002
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

**TestAccountController**

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class TestAccountController {
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        private AccountService accountService;

        @InjectMocks
        private AccountController accountController;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void findLocationTest() throws Exception {

            Account account = new Account();
            account.setsLocation("US");
            account.setsLocation("pune");

            List<Account> accountObj = new ArrayList<Account>();
            accountObj.add(account);

            Mockito.when(accountService.findLocation()).thenReturn(accountObj);

            mockMvc.perform(get("/api.spacestudy.com/spacestudy/rockefeller/admin/account/loadAcctLocationList"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sLocation", is("pune")));
        }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'crossOrigin' in value "${crossOrigin}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.resolveCorsAnnotationValue(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.updateCorsConfig(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:319)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.initCorsConfiguration(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.initCorsConfiguration(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:250)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:490)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.registerMvcSingletons(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:356)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.initWebAppContext(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:341)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.AbstractMockMvcBuilder.build(AbstractMockMvcBuilder.java:139)
    at com.spacestudy.controller.TestAccountController.setup(TestAccountController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Do you have a Java configuration for your context?

Comment: No I don't have any configuration file

Comment: I resolved it by adding a space between the dollar and first brace { but I didn't understood reason behind that

Comment: when I am adding space in between $ and first brace { test cases in running but In angular side I am getting error cross origin request block

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is over a year old, however I too ran into this issue.

The solution is one needs to provide the MockMvc with the place holder value.

So the following :

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
```

Should be :

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).addPlaceholderValue("crossOrigin","https://some.url.com").build();
```